# Is there a 64-bit plugin for Google App Engine in eclipse?

Tags: google-app-engine, eclipse-plugin, 64-bit

So I have the 64-bit Windows version of Eclipse installed.

I'm curious -

- Is there a 64-bit build of the Google App Engine plugin?
- Is it acceptable to install the 32-bit Google App Engine plugin on the Eclipse x64 installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The GAE plugin is written in Java, so there is no 32 and 64 bit version. You need to have 64 bit Java runtime, but compiled code is always the same.